# Babel with node server on openshift. How do I fix this?

Tags: node.js

How do I run node server on openshift with babel? it seems to crash when include babel. I don't have permission to do su or sudo on openshift.

**node start.js**

start.js file

```
fs.js:584
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/lib/openshift/56f34cb02d5271ecd40001d0/.babel.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1224:33)
    at save (/var/lib/openshift/56f34cb02d5271ecd40001d0/app-deployments/2016-03-23_22-16-04.002/repo/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/cache.js:35:19)
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:376:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:407:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
    at startup (node.js:142:18)
    at node.js:939:3
```

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Ya I fixed it by setting the environment variable BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1. I think I did rhc set-env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 --app myapp